# How to encode a JavaScript URL correctly if it contains special characters?

Tags: javascript, html, url, encode

I'm going to add below JavaScript on my website:

```
<script src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=15795206&PluID=0&w=300&h=250&ncu=$$http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net$$&ord=123&ucm=true"></script>
```

You can see that there is a special character "$" in the JavaScript URL.

In order to load it correctly, I encode the "$" into "%24"

```
<script src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=15795206&PluID=0&w=300&h=250&ncu=%24%24%http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net%24%24%&ord=123&ucm=true"></script>
```

It works fine as expected. If I copy the URL into the browser address bar, it will load the JavaScript file successfully:

[image]

**Here comes to my question: When should I encode a specific character in a URL (such as the above "$" case), and when should I encode the whole URL?**

I tried to encode the whole URL so that it will become:

```
<script src="http%3A%2F%2Fbs.serving-sys.com%2FBurstingPipe%2FadServer.bs%3Fcn%3Drsb%26c%3D28%26pli%3D15795206%26PluID%3D0%26w%3D300%26h%3D250%26ncu%3D%24%24http%3A%2F%2Fadclick.g.doubleclick.net%24%24%26ord%3D123%26ucm%3Dtrue"></script>
```

However, if I paste the URL into the browser's address bar, it just can't work:

[image]

Why is that?? Thanks.

Comment: You don't urlencode the entire adress, it's just for data being sent, as in querystring params.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use encodeURI();

Like this:

```
encodeURI(something/somethingelse.js?something1=1&something2=3);
```